# change android development device id

Tags: android, adb

I'd like to connect multiple android devices to the same machine and manage them by the adb. Unfortunately some android models show the same development device id to adb. Is there a way to change the development device id?

```
$ adb devices
List of devices attached 
LG_ANDROID_E0OPEN_GB_   device
LG_ANDROID_E0OPEN_GB_   device
```

Please note that this question is related to [9786928](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9786928/how-can-i-change-the-device-name-adb-devices). As I understand it, the OP was misunderstood and the question is still not answered.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: AFAIK, this is baked into the OS and you can't change it. Custom roms sometimes have this problem since they might use the same "id". Are you using a custom rom on these devices?

Comment: sudo for adb ? are you really sure that you know what you are doing ? You probably have messed up with something and the development on custom roms is your business.

Comment: @A--C: I unboxed the devices myself and didn't tamper with them. Maybe LG messed it up.

Comment: @user1797612: You're right sudo isn't relevant to this example. I tried sudo to explore another problem. I edited it out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the LG E400, there is a firmware update (V10i-JUN-01-2012) available that addresses this issue.

Before update I've seen the same ID like you for all devices, after update the devices have unique ids.

Answer (score 4):

Not without altering adb.  The adb "server" (i.e. the part that runs on your workstation) just uses the value it gets from the device, which are in turn set by the bootloader.  You could in theory modify the adb server to include additional information in the string, such as the USB device number assigned when the device was plugged in (if you're on Linux, run `lsusb` and imagine the "bus" and "device" values are included in the device ID).

You may also be able to do this by installing a custom ROM.

Comment: it's clearly not the answer I wanted to hear. I have to accept it anyway I guess.

Comment: You can ask the OEM (which I assume is LG) to fix their devices, and you can ask AOSP to provide a workaround for this in adb (which by definition won't be perfect, but might be good enough).  You're kinda hosed for the moment, but this should be fixable.

Comment: I did exactly that, changed the way adb differentiates devices on usb bus: http://stackoverflow.com/a/22824288/21009