# adb got two same serial numbers when connected to two smart phones

Tags: android, adb

I have two smart phones (**ZTEV788d**, system **Android 2.3.6**) connected to a computer (**Ubuntu 11.10**) at the same time, using command: `adb devices` I got this:

```
List of devices attached
P753A12D    device
P753A12D    device
```

The serial numbers are the same!

I wrote an application in the computer side to communicate with these two phones, for example install app and push files.

I used these commands:

```
adb -s P753A12D install XXX.apk
adb -s P753A12D push XXX /sdcard
```

Now these two phones have the same serial no (`P753A12D`), when I run these commands I get this error:

```
error:more than one device
```

So, my questions are:

1. Is that normal that two phones to have the same serial no?
2. Can I change the serial no? if yes, how?
3. Is there any way to run these install, push commands successfully even if the serial no are the same?

BTW, the WiFi/3G network will be turned off when I'll run the test.

Comment: When only one device is attached at a time, does one of them show a different number?

Comment: When only one phone is attached, the serial number is P753A12D too, just the same number as two phones attached.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13868411/change-android-development-device-id/

Answer (score 26):

Today I found an easy solution for this issue.

```
adb devices -l
```

You'll get list of devices with their qualifiers

```
List of devices attached
P753A12D device usb:26200000 transport_id:1
P753A12D device usb:24400000 transport_id:2
```

Then you can use qualifiers instead of serial numbers like this

```
adb -s usb:26200000 install xxx.apk
```

or with `transport_id` and `-t`

```
adb -t 1 install xxx.apk
```

Comment: This doesn't seem to work on my Windows box as I get the first one showing up with a long listing but the second one always shows up as 'offline'.  Part of the problem, I think, is that the long listing doesn't show the usb identifier but uses the model number as in 'device:XXXXX' instead of 'usb:yyyy'

Comment: Now `adb` support `-t ID  use device with given transport id`, you could also use like `adb -t 1 install xxx.apk`

Comment: Thanks, will add up it to the answer.

Answer (score 9):

**if your device is rooted**

try this way
 to change serial number your devices , first connect one of them to your pc then type this in cmd

```
adb devices
```

this shows your device id (serial number).

```
List of devices attached
P753A12D    device
```

pick some new name ,for example **NAME1**
then type this commands

```
adb shell
su 
device_name="NEW_NAME"
cd /sys/class/android_usb/android0/
echo -n $device_name > iSerial
cat iSerial
```

`exit` exit from root 
`exit` exit from shell

**START**
now  **unplug the usb cable**  and run this commands

```
adb kill-server
```

connect your device again and type

```
adb devices
```

now you can see changes

```
List of devices attached
New_NAME    device
```

**END**
**note : if it did not work first time**
disconnect your phone and do this parts of my guide from **START** to **END** again.

Comment: After days of searching online, trying countless tricks, this worked for me, Thanks a lot!!!!

Comment: Thanks! Definitely what I was looking for!

Answer (score 6):

I faced the very same problem. It's because the adb tool uses the serial numbers for identification of devices connected to usb instead of their device paths (which are unique for sure).

If you feel up to getting your hands dirty, download the Android source tree, go to `system/core/adb/transport.c`, change it to something like that:

```
void register_usb_transport(usb_handle *usb, const char *serial, const char *devpath, unsigned writeable)
{
    atransport *t = calloc(1, sizeof(atransport));
    D("transport: %p init'ing for usb_handle %p (sn='%s')\n", t, usb,
      serial ? serial : "");
    init_usb_transport(t, usb, (writeable ? CS_OFFLINE : CS_NOPERM));
//    if(serial) {
//        t->serial = strdup(serial);
//    }
    if(devpath) {
        t->devpath = strdup(devpath);
        t->serial = strdup(devpath);
    }
```

type `make adb` from the top level path and voila. Devices use usb paths for identification. Now you can install & execute all of the devices from Eclipse with one click.

Comment: It turns out that this doesn't seem to work for Windows.  If you look at the file usb_windows.cpp where register_usb_transport is called it appears to always be called with devpath set to NULL.

Answer (score 5):

### 1. Is that normal that two phones to have the same serial number?

The purpose of the serial number is to uniquely identify the device, so they should be different. That being said, some manufacturers don't bother. It's also possible that the firmware is reporting the number incorrectly.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4636794/strange-output-of-adb-devices?rq=1

You can check the serial number on the actual devices, and see if it matches what `adb` is reporting.

```
Settings > About Device > Phone Identity > Device Serial Number
```

---

### 2. Can I change the serial number? if yes, how?

There isn't an easy or consistent method for doing this that I'm aware of. Here are some examples where others have accomplished this feat (but I have not):

[xda-developers.com - Change Wifi , BT , IMEI , Serial Number of any mtk android phone](http://forum.xda-developers.com/crossdevice-dev/android-one-general/change-wifi-bt-imei-serial-mtk-android-t3058850)

[hugestreet.info - How To Change IMEI, Device ID of Any Android Device](http://forum.xda-developers.com/crossdevice-dev/android-one-general/change-wifi-bt-imei-serial-mtk-android-t3058850)

---

### 3. Is there any way to run these install, push commands successfully even if the serial numbers are the same?

There shouldn't be any problem running commands if only one device is connected at a time.

Comment: I checked the actual devices,the serial number is the same in these two phones. thanks Codeshane!

Comment: You're welcome. Were you able to get this working? If you're happy with my answer, please "accept" it, otherwise please let me know what else I can do.  thanks!

Comment: The link to mailinglistarchive.com is dead. Could you update it?

Answer (score 1):

The answer given by @mirokropacek works for Linux (and presumably Mac, too) but doesn't work for Windows, unfortunately.  This is due to the way the `register_usb_transport` function is called in Windows.  It turns out the devpath parameter is always `NULL` in Windows.  I needed to handle the same situation so I adapted the solution given above to randomly generate a device ID for each device if the `serial` parameter is NULL or it is empty (zero length).

I don't need to worry about differentiating devices over long periods of time and many devices so generating a pseudo-random number for the device ID with `rand`, then using `sprintf` to create a string representation of that ID seems to be sufficient for my needs but YMMV.  It only generates a 4-digit hex number but it works well enough for me (for now at least).

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to change the device itself, and/or don't have root access, and the device has network access, you could switch to using TCPIP instead of USB:

1. Switch adb to using TCPIP: `adb tcpip 5555`
2. Have adb connect to the device using the network: `adb connect yourhostname`

I've run this through SSH tunnels where it would connect to localhost, so all devices show up as 'localhost' which is quite unuseful. Adding hosts to /etc/hosts (that all pointed to localhost) fixed that for me.

Answer (score 0):

Additionally you can use below commands when to handle multiple instance attached (device + emulator)

```
adb -d shell #(or adb -e shell if you're connecting to an emulator).
```

`-d` stands for device and `-e` stands for emulator