# adb got same serial number when two phone are connected on a pc. Can I change the serial number?

Tags: android, eclipse, adb, serial-number

I have two devices connected at the same time to a computer.
If I use command: adb devices, adb got this:

List of devices attached 
0123456789ABCDEF  device
0123456789ABCDEF  device

So, the devices have the same serial number! 
I want to manage both devices via USB for debugging my application, but I have this error:

[2013-01-21 20:28:12 - DeviceMonitor] Failed to start monitoring 0123456789ABCDEF
                                     : more than one device

I think I have this error because the devices have the same serial number.
I read other discussions and I try these instructions on terminal:

$ su

## getprop net.hostname

android-b112064be9bfd82

So..0123456789ZBCDEF isn't the serial number.

Someone know how can I change the serial number?
Sorry for my bad english.

Comment: see this similar [question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/14334656/1904517)

Comment: I have just read this discussion, but I think I don't understand what it means "populate /sys/class/android_usb/android0/iSerial sysfs file with unique values for every device"
I'll search on Google what it means.
Thank you for answer!

Answer (score 1):

To temporarily (until reboot) change the ADB serial number, disconnect all but one of the devices and type this in a command window:

```
adb shell 'echo -n "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX" > /sys/class/android_usb/android0/iSerial'
```

where the X's represent the desired serial number. *This change **requires root** and will only last until the device is rebooted.* To make it permanent, you'd need to alter one of the system startup scripts to make the change.

*Note that this doesn't seem to work as often on newer devices; the file location has apparently changed.*

Comment: I got 'permission denied' when trying this against a non-rooted device.  Is this supposed to work on a non-rooted device?

Comment: Yes, you do need root on the device.

Comment: after change serial:adb kill-server && adb start-server

Comment: I use the same trick for a while now (remember using `echo -n` for that, to avoid the trailing line feed). I'd prefer to make that permanent, but there doesn't seem to be a "universal way" to achieve that unfortunately.