# How to change the serial number (or ID in ADB devices)

Tags: android, adb, serial-number

I was sewing a handset for root, IMEI and Syrian failed, in principle I don’t care about them, but in adb I have this:

List of devices attached
07546371C3002567 device
088783727N004245 device

## H6125KG501234567 device

## H6125KG501234567 device

Please tell me how to change the ID of the handsets? There is no need to restore it, just change it so that the software can connect via ADB.

Phone: tecno spark go 2022
Android 11

I tried everything that was already written on the site :)
phones are connected via USB

[link 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14446500/adb-got-same-serial-number-when-two-phone-are-connected-on-a-pc-can-i-change-th)
[link 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14334656/same-serial-number-on-several-android-devices-adb-is-useless-how-can-i-change)

Comment: "I tried everything that was already written on the site" please tell us the commands you tried (not just link, include the commands you have executed and what was going wrong).