# Can I use the Serial number to uniquely identify android device ? (API >= 9)

Tags: java, android, uniqueidentifier

I'm a newbie on Android. I try to find a way to get unique android device id which can not be change when reset or root device. Then I found the "Pseudo ID" at https://stackoverflow.com/a/17625641/1654338. Maybe it's the best possible option to get it now. But I still have some questions:

1. The Serial number ( android.os.Build.class.getField("SERIAL").get(null).toString(); ). I wondering It can be change when root android device ? It still be ok on device without root permission, right? I know it represents the hardware serial number. But It's the constant or not, because imei also can be change with a rooted device.
2. I read this post: [Same serial number on several android devices. Adb is useless. How can I change the serial number?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14334656/same-serial-number-on-several-android-devices-adb-is-useless-how-can-i-change). Is it easy to change SERIAL ?
3. The serial number is null on Samsung Galaxy Tab because "ro.serialno" isn't set on this device, I read from Stack Overflow post. So the technically's also missing serial number although API >= 9, right? How much is the ratio ?

I should ask Jared Burrows to get him answer, but I left a message "I wrote this 1.5+ years ago. I am not sure why it is not unique for you. You can try the advertising ID. If not, you can come up with your own solution".

Anyone has experience about this, please help me.
Thank for reading my question.

Comment: why not your going for MAC address ?

Comment: pleas check this because i am also using [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10831578/how-to-find-mac-address-of-an-android-device-programatically) for identifing my PDAS

Comment: Thank @MahaKhan, MAC address is ok, but i don't want to require user another permission

Comment: Why your not making your own algorithm ? like serial number with macaddress and user name i mean u can think this way too ;)

Comment: thank you, i have no answer for this question. Finally, I used Pseudo-Unique ID. In my opinion, that's an acceptable risk. Just wanted to let you know