# How to change default device id 0123456789ABCDEF with Eclipse or adt?

Tags: android, eclipse, adt

I am developing an Android app and need to test it on multiple devices.

However, adt (and, by extension, Eclipse) seem to give them a "default" id 0123456789ABCDEF. When deploying my app to the device, Eclipse complains: `more than one device`.

I've managed to get a distinct id read for each device:

```
$ ./adb devices -l
List of devices attached
0123456789ABCDEF       device usb:14110000
0123456789ABCDEF       device usb:14122000
0123456789ABCDEF       device usb:14121000
0123456789ABCDEF       device usb:14123000
0123456789ABCDEF       device usb:14124000
```

But I can't manage to use this `device usb:XXXXX` string anywhere to point Eclipse to the terminal I want to launch the app on.

Currently my solution is to connect only one device at a time, but this is very cumbersome. Does anybody know how can I either change a device ID or make Eclipse refer to the correct one when all of them are connected at the same time?

Thanks a lot

---

Okay, here's the solution, thanks a lot for the provided references:

As stated [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22824288/2846258), I needed to recompile `adb`

First, download Android source code as stated in the official instructions. Then, modify `adb` as stated in the previous link. Finally, restart the adb server, and you will see a different string for each phone, which then can be used to open a shell, deploy .apk, etc.

Comment: Hi Carlos, am getting this same serial number issue, while fetching the device serial number problematically. any solution on this.          ref my question also. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50578795/android-fetching-device-serial-number-same-for-some-of-device-models