# Using adb with multiple devices with the same serial number

Tags: android, adb

There are two devices connected with my computer.But when I start the adb, both of them have the serial number "0123456789ABCDEF".

When I try to install an APK, the installation fails with "more than one device" error message.
[image]

In addition, I am developing a Bluetooth app, I need to use both of the two devices simultaneously.

Comment: `adb devices` command shows two devices with the same name?

Comment: Try to install one by one.

Comment: @ hegazy   yes,it does.

Comment: Try make adb command. Refer to:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13986155/adb-got-two-same-serial-numbers-when-connected-to-two-smart-phones

Comment: Do you use Android studio or Eclipse to install the APK on the devices ? Or are you using the adb command line ?

Comment: Can you please include the adb output showing 2 devices with the same name?  (hint: the command I would like to see is the output from: adb devices)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Maybe I can help you, I was able to solve this issue by changing the device ID/Serial:

1. `adb shell`
2. `cd /sys/class/android_usb/android0/`
3. `echo -n xxx > iSerial` (the xxx is the device id you want)
4. `cat iSerial` (check the new device id)
5. Unplug usb cable and plug again, then the change worked.

To change each id, your PC should only be connected to one device via usb.

Comment: Didn't work on my devices...

Comment: Toni, you might need to use "su" if you don't have the permissions. Not sure if this will solve your problem but since my devices were rooted it just worked...

Comment: You must have **ROOT access** for this purpose. Otherwise: _/system/bin/sh: can't create iSerial: Permission denied_.

Answer (score 14):

`adb devices -l` command prints out some additional device parameters which can also be used with `adb -s`. Obviously it would help only if any of those extra parameters are unique. Fortunately for `linux` and `osx` users `adb devices -l` in those systems also reports unique `USB` port numbers:

```
$ adb devices -l
List of devices attached
XXXXXXXXXX             device usb:2-1.6.7.7 product:shamu model:Nexus_6 device:shamu

$ adb -s usb:2-1.6.7.7 shell
shell@shamu:/ $
```