# adb error: more than one device - android

Tags: android, adb

I have 2 Android devices connected via usb to my pc

now when i list devices i get this:

```
C:\Users\MBH>adb devices
List of devices attached
0123456789ABCDEF        device
0123456789ABCDEF        device
```

Both devices got the same serial number, or whatever this **0123456789ABCDEF** means.

**The problem:** I am not able to do anything in this case, neither pushing or pulling files, nor forwarding tcp ports.

```
C:\Users\MBH>adb forward tcp:59900 tcp:59900
error: more than one device/emulator

C:\Users\MBH>adb -s 0123456789ABCDEF forward tcp:59900 tcp:59900
error: more than one device
```

**The question:** is there anyway to connect or select device in different way? like device model number or something?

Comment: i need them to be connected, i am working on both of them at the same time @Rohit5k2

Comment: switch your device to camera(PTP) instead of USB storage

Comment: I did, still the same @AmarbirSingh

Comment: it is usually `adb command -s`. Btw `forward` does not support `-s` (accordingly to the man page)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13986155/adb-got-two-same-serial-numbers-when-connected-to-two-smart-phones          http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30214744/using-adb-with-multiple-devices-with-the-same-serial-number

Answer (score 38, accepted):

I got it

```
C:\Users\MBH>adb devices -l
List of devices attached
0123456789ABCDEF       device product:ZEN model:ZEN device:ZEN
0123456789ABCDEF       device product:full_gs702c model:M757 device:gs702c
```

Then I could use the model number for shelling

```
C:\Users\MBH>adb -s model:M757 shell
shell@gs702c:/ $ ls
```

it works now

Answer (score 43):

You can run every command of adb by selecting the device by deviceID.
run command to get Device Id:

```
adb devices
```

you will get the list of all available devices something like this:

```
<device ID> device
emulator-5554 offline
```

the copy the device id run commad like this:

```
adb -s <device ID> <your command>
```

example:

```
adb -s <device ID> tcpip 5555
```

OR

```
adb -s <device ID> forward tcp:59900 tcp:59900
```

this will not get the error like "more than one device/emulator"

Thanks

Comment: but both devices got the same id and that was the problem already

Comment: great answer and tutorial!