# Automatically install android app on the devices after build/commit

Tags: android, android-studio, installation

I am developing android app and to test it I need it to run on several devices. So it is really pain to reinstall it on every device when change is done. Is there any way to make app install automatically after I hit build in android studio or something similar?

Comment: android studio already have that feature.  press `ctrl+F10` with device connected through usb it will build and install it through usb debugging

Comment: I need through the internet and on all the devices automatically

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it not proper but yes we can do it

connect all device to same wifi network

connect device to pc and type command

> adb tcpip 5555

it can perform all device

after check ip address of mobile

> goto setting>about>ip address

after type this command to connect wireless

> adb connect ipaddress

after all device connect you can run app using shift+F10 or run button click

select all device and hit the run button

it can run in all device

more detail see this artical

1) http://codetheory.in/android-debug-bridge-adb-wireless-debugging-over-wi-fi/

2) [adb error: more than one device - android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35269473/adb-error-more-than-one-device-android)

Comment: Thanks! will try that