# adb got two same serial numbers, how to solve without root

Tags: android, adb

I use **adb** for update application using USB on multiple devices. I works great but suddenly I noticed that my client uses terrible `Irbis` tablets which have **same** serial no - `0123456789ABCDEF`.

I read all topics about this problem, such as [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13986155/adb-got-two-same-serial-numbers-when-connected-to-two-smart-phones) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30214744/using-adb-with-multiple-devices-with-the-same-serial-number).

Devices are not rooted, so I cant just change serial.

I cant use WiFi instead of USB.

[That](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13986155/adb-got-two-same-serial-numbers-when-connected-to-two-smart-phones) would be perfect solution if I only could get USB identifier. The problem is that:

```
adb devices -l
```

returns only

> List of devices attached
>
> 0123456789ABCDEF       device product:TZ85
>   model:TZ85 device:TZ85

So I cant use command using

```
adb -s usb:26200000 install xxx.apk
```

Is there any solution?

Any help will be appreciated.

**UPDATE:**
My OS is Windows 10

I noticed that in Settings of the device serial number is different than ADB shows.

Comment: What operating system are you using on the host?

Comment: @chiastic-security Windows 10.

Comment: Hmm, I think you might need to get a proper operating system if you want to be able to solve this. I don't know whether Windows will give you enough control to be able to identify and address the individual ports.

Comment: The question is still a duplicate - even if you are not willing to accept the existing answers