# How to change the device name? (wifi adb)

Tags: android, adb, android-wifi

I usually debug with [Wifi adb](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.ttxapps.wifiadb). Everything work fine. But the length of devices name are 
big!.

It's usually are wifi IP + 5555.

I've tried [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9786928/how-can-i-change-the-device-name-adb-devices) but devices name not change.

How to shorten that name?

Comment: How big is big? Why does it bother you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't do that, really. However, to simplify your debugging, you can define environment variable `ANDROID_SERIAL` with your target device name, something like:

```
export ANDROID_SERIAL=192.168.123.123:5555
```

After that, `adb` will connect with this device by default.

Comment: Your idea is using environments to shorten. It's not using android way but solved my problem. Thanks you so much ^^