# Differantiate devices with similar model and os version connected to computer with android studio

Tags: android, android-studio, android-emulator, android-ide

I have 3 tablets with from the same model with the same android version.
I want to be able to differ between devices quickly. 
I will just show the problem,

[image]

Is their a way to differentiate them on this combo box?
Thanks,
Ilan

**UPDATE**:

I have posted a bug google about this. I Its a problem for you to, vote for this bug [here](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=195986) .

Comment: I'd suggest looking at this [previous question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9786928/how-can-i-change-the-device-name-adb-devices)

Answer (score 0):

Try this in your device,

```
Homescreen -> press menu -> System settings -> applications -> development -> Device name
```

Here you can change the devices name which is shown in **android studio**.

Comment: changed but I don't se a change in the android studio combo box.