# android emulator renaming from emulator-5554 to a unique string

Tags: android, android-emulator, adb

So when on starting up an emulator , adb devices give me

> emulator-5554 device

All dandy till here.

What i am envisioning is to create an emulator farm with multiple emulators spawned up on multiple devices. In order to uniquely differentiate from an emulator-5554 running on machine A from emulator-5554 running on machine B ,I would like to rename emulator-5554(s) to something like machineA-emulator-5554 and machineB-emulator-5554. Searching around did not find me much help ( as a majority of the questions were regarding actual device renaming). Any pointers on the above?

NP:I had tried to do a setprop on serialno with a random string
and then checked to see whether it actually changed ( and it had)

> root@generic_x86:/ # getprop persist.usb.serialno
>
> 76876987gg

Weirdly running adb devices gave me a status of

> emulator-5554 offline

The emulator name did not change and the status went offline. Am i missing something here?

Comment: It would be great if the person downvoting could explain the reason for the downvote.

Comment: After 3 years, were you able to find a solution to this issue?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can't change the adb generated name, but you can change the port number.
You need to start the emulator with command line.

Go to emulator directory: ... \Android\Sdk\emulator

Use this command.

```
./emulator –port <port number> -avd "emulator name" <options>
```

For example:

```
./emulator –port 5558 -avd MyEMU
```

In `adb devices` your device is now emulator-5558.

Answer (score 5):

`adb` server scans range of `TCP` ports and when it finds something listening on those ports it registers it as a device with the `emulator-XXXX` name. No configuration of the device itself can change that. You could either modify the `adb` code to implement your custom naming scheme or just use some other facility to identify your emulator instances.

Comment: Oh so is it  an " emulator-only" thing ? I had come across posts which dealt with topics around renaming the device( physical devices) id names shown through adb devices.
[link to the post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9786928/how-can-i-change-the-device-name-adb-devices)