# adb blinks with 'emulator-5554 [DISCONNECTED]'

Tags: android, adb

[image]

I've a device connected via USB (Samsung SM-T385 - Type C Port) and I don't have any emulator created in my system.

OS : `Ubuntu 16.04`

ADB Version : `Android Debug Bridge version 1.0.40 ; Version 28.0.2-5303910`

**Problem**

Even though I haven't added any emulator, adb blinks with `emulator-5554 [DISCONNECTED]` like above. Sometimes even the real device is not getting detected, and shows just the blink text. This issue also occurred to one of my colleagues. He uses a Windows 10.

**What worked?**

- Restarting the system solved this issue for an hour or less,then the issue rises again.

**What didn't work?**

- `adb kill-server`
- Kill adb from process list
- Restarting Android Studio

**Question**

- How do I fix this issue, without restarting the system ?

Comment: Assuming ANDROID_HOME is the path of the root sdk folder, post the result of this command: `$ANDROID_HOME/tools/bin/avdmanager list avd`

Comment: @SepehrBehroozi https://i.stack.imgur.com/YnBaU.png

Comment: This issue is killing me! clean re-installed android studio twice, no fix! :'(

Answer (score 0):

Change your port number in Android studio setting page

[image]

Comment: Please add some explanation to your answer such that others can learn from it - what makes you think that changing the port number solves the original problem?

Answer (score -1):

Here is the answer: [Blinking option in Connected Devices list that won't let me debug any app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54333036/blinking-option-in-connected-devices-list-that-wont-let-me-debug-any-app)

but basically the answer is it is videostream app... uninstall that and fixed!