# Blinking emulator device in Android Studio and problem on debugging

Tags: android-emulator

I have a trouble in Android Studio on debugging devices.
On start debugging on USB or any installed emulation devices (AVD), I get following error in debug console:

```
Device emulator-5554disconnected, monitoring stopped.
```

The application after install don't wanna start and i can't continue my debugging.

In the devices selection menu i can see "EMULATOR-5554" that blinking

[emulator-blink](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RqZOk.png)

to

[emulator-blink2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MCEWC.png)

I tried to restart ADB **but it works only first time**, after rebuild it stop working

I tried to uninstall Android Studio and removed these folders without benefits

```
C:\Users\[name]\.android
C:\Users\[name]\AppData\Local\Android
```

I tried with a new project but it still not work

I tried to close Android Studio, then i checked with ADB command prompt the devices and the emulator-5554 doesn't exists, it will appear after Android Studio start

Comment: This issue is killing me! clean re-installed android studio twice, no fix. gonna have to wipe my machine! :'(

Comment: I have the same issue. Did you find a solution? @SnowyTracks

Comment: @FlorianCargoet Yes, you have to find out what else is listening on the emulator port.. in my case it was Videostream.... I uninstalled it and it stopped blinking... more info here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54333036/blinking-option-in-connected-devices-list-that-wont-let-me-debug-any-app

Comment: @SnowyTracks Thanks. I've tried killing the process but it automatically launches again. I use videostream too often to uninstall it. Instead, I search & replaced the port numbers in Videostream.app

Comment: @FlorianCargoet how did you change that videostream port?

Comment: @DenDrobiazko I changed the source code of the videostream app. On OSX, it's in `/Applications/Videostream.app/Contents/Resources/lib/index.js` and `/Applications/Videostream.app/Contents/Resources/public/js/desktop.js`. I changed all occurences of 5556 and 5557 to 15556 and 15557.