# I keep getting unknown device to appear and disappear in the devices list (Emulator-5554)

Tags: android-studio, adb

I keep getting unknown device to appear and disappear in the devices list (Emulator-5554)

There's nothing running on port 5554.

Images:
[image]

No devices

And
[image]

Unknown device (Appears briefly)

Could someone please help me figure what could be going on?

Comment: When I click the green run button, it sometimes fails because Android Studio thinks I'm trying to run the app on the 'Unknown Device'

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/42536581/1778421

Comment: @AlexP.Thank you for the comment. I mentioned the note 'There's nothing running on port 5554.' for this reason.

Comment: Unfortunately, there's nothing on the port to de-activate